# ASP Session Variable Lost On Some Computers

Tags: session, asp-classic, session-variables

I'm having a problem with ASP Session objects.
I set a session variable on one page:

```
Session("QuestionAmount") = 1
```

On some computers when I use this variable on another page in the site it works just fine, however on other computers it seems to get lost. I've also noticed that on some computers where it doesnt work, it will work on another browser.
My question therefore is:
Are session variables not supported by all browsers? (I would've thought they are) as google chrome surprisingly is the browser on which it works least. And is there anything I can do to overcome this problem?

Comment: ASP Session object uses cookies to maintain it's state look at your browsers cookie accept policy.

Comment: Also They can be counfigured as cookiless

Comment: @Def Again the .net references?? Sessions "out of the box" in [tag:asp-classic] do not provide a cookieless option, you're thinking of a bespoke solution which is not supported by default.

Comment: Cookies are enabled on the computers that aren't working

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would affect that is cookies, if your sure that your session cookies are not being blocked and sorry but I'm out of ideas unless you can provide some more information about your setup.

Comment: @howdybaby What version of iis do the application lunch from?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help everyone. In the end I just reverted to storing data in the url and using request.querystring and it worked just fine. Though all your contributions were read and were helpful for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Session is an Server object that lives with it. You configure your session in web.config there you can configure it on many ways. If it stores in process it can cause one kind of problems in sql another will apear. May be it is just a timeout there, because the user was idle for a long time(deafult lifetime 20 min)  [for more information about seesion go there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

try to figure out is session ever began or had been ended with

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
   // your code here
  }
```

In my opinion It is a problem with session configuration. Try to config Session to store itself in SqlServer. Example of such cfg could be found in topic i gave.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, it's asp-classic, but following information about Session completely true for asp-classic also. just convert C# to VBS/ASP :)

Comment: @Zam it's not and depends on what version of IIS you're running [tag:asp-classic] on. For example session start and end is configured in global.asa under your asp application not the web.config file. The information is completely mismatched not to mention in the wrong programming language.

Comment: @Lankymart I said that  session properties can be configured in web.config. But ask to figure out if session was started or ended in global.asax file. It was 2 points of my suggestions what was wrong.

Comment: @Def Seriously? `global.asa` not `global.asax` you're making my point for me.

Comment: @Def Your link even points to an article about ASP.Net Session State? This is not ASP.Net it is Classic ASP I don't think I can be any clearer.

Comment: @Lankymart both (asp-classic session and .net session) is based on IIS sessions wich props is listed there [link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session) this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754450(v=ws.10).aspx) is about session cfg in IIS 7.0. Also both global.asa and global.asax have the events i listed.

Comment: @Def Your making quite a large assumption that the OP is using IIS 7 or above, none of this advice is relevant if he happens to still be using IIS 6 or below.

Comment: I have to agree with @Lankymart here, the question is about classic ASP so same way that answer explaining about [Session in Ruby on Rails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm) won't be valid, this one isn't valid as well. Classic ASP and ASP.NET are **different languages** and it's very common mistake to think they are the same.